# is jcop is only way to install applet in java card?

Tags: javacard

I am trying to understand the concept of java card , I have some doubts , I want to share with , perhaps you would any best suggestion for me.

### //Jcop-  I read somewhere that Java Card OpenPlatform (JCOP) is a smart card operating system for the Java Card platform developed by IBM Zürich Research Laboratory.

**question 1**- if this above sentence is right it means jcop is an operating system  developed by IBM, handle all operation inside the card.right?
I have a card which indicate

### ATR like- 3b 89 80 01 4a ....40 ( in character form it indicate- ;---jcop41v22m) ,

so can i say? this is a card which o.s is made by IBM. and we require only and only  JCOP tool to send cap  inside this card because OS inside is JCOP and jcop tool would be the only option to talk to jCOp card?

**question 2**- or is there any other method by which i can send the applet inside my card?

```
    enable_trace
    establish_context
    card_connect
    select -AID a0000000030000
    open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f // Open secure channel
    delete -AID D0D1D2D3D4D50101
    delete -AID D0D1D2D3D4D501
    delete -AID D0D1D2D3D4D50101
    install -file helloworld.cap -nvDataLimit 500 -instParam 00 -priv 2
    # getdata
    # close_sc // Close secure channel
    # putkey // Put key

  // options:
  //          -keyind Key index
  //          -keyver Key version
  //          -key Key value in hex
card_disconnect
release_context`
```

**question 3**- above code i got from gpshell 1.4.4 , the code style indictate that this is also a method tp send  cap file inside the java card, I want to know that for my card case { atr is -3b 89 80 01 4a ....40 ( in character form it indicate- ;---jcop41v22m)} , I can apply gpshell to send .cap file in my card.

**question 4**-  is gpshell is used to send cap into a  special java card which is not jcop enable or which does not contaion jcop operating system?

there are so many techniques , so many type of java card, it makes me confuse , I hope you seems this question genuine and would give me revert back
regards:-

Comment: Please research Java Card before asking questions, and certainly before creating a Smart Card implementation, because you are clearly lacking experience to create an Applet that has to be deployed in the field, come back if you've got any *specific* questions.

Answer (score 3):

The question is good. I see a lot of people that work with smart card for years and cannot still get the picture.

What you read is right JCOP is operating system for smart cards.

Although it is NOT true that you have to use JCOP tool to deploy applets. They might be helpful but it is not the only way. In fact what you need to know is what version of Global Platform is supported by your card. Global Platform is the standard that defines how Card Contend is managed. This includes installation, security concept and so on. For example if your card support GP 2.1.1 you should use this document as a reference:

http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/Card%20Spec%20v2.1.1%20v0303.pdf

All the tools like gpshell, jcshell are wrapping global platform commands in more user friendly commands, and also implementing the security protocols for you. So you can use whatever tool that supports the GP version of your target card.

I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the subject of the question is:

NO.

Have a look at https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatform

Answer (score 2):

NXP currently owns JCOP, you should go to them for questions.

1. Yes, the VM inside a Java Card implementation executes all byte code.
2. You can use any Global Platform compatible library, although there are some implementation mistakes that could make a difference.
3. Try it, it should work
4. Java Card is a standard, and implementations are tested by Oracle, so sending your Applet to another card should work *1

*1 unless you make assumptions that are not cleared up in Java Card, use too much stack or heap memory for that card, use crypto algorithms that are not present, Java Card API's that have not been implemented by the other card, or of course, proprietary JCOP functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1 is "no". You shouldn't rely on the historical bytes `"jcop41v22"` in the ATR to recognize the type of card. Any Java Card applet can change these bytes.

Comment: Did you mean we can change the ATR using an applet?!! If so, how?! Thanks

Comment: Make your applet the default selectable applet and call [`GPSystem.setATRHistBytes`](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/gp22/org/globalplatform/GPSystem.html).

Answer (score 1):

Q1&Q2: No.It's right that Java Card OpenPlatform (JCOP) is a smart card operating system for the Java Card platform.But it's not the only tool to deploy applet. For example,i'm using [PyAPDUTool](http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=38) to send cap file inside the java card.

Q3: Yes,you can use gpshell to send .cap file in your card.

Q4: NO,you can also send your applet to other javacards.

Answer (score 0):

NO.
You can take a look at this website "www.javacos.com" . On this the tool of jcide also can get what you want And it is free of charge.Although some function is not very perfect.