# Java card applet convert to .cap file

Tags: java, converters, javacard

I am new to java card development.so I have created java card simple applet using java card 2.2.2. Can anyone tell me how to convert javacard applet to (.cap)file easily.And also what are the tools we can used.

Thanks
SSV

Comment: Have you looked at this [Oracle product](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10439754/27190) (free), this [NXP product](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9504328/27190) (not-free), and this [G+D product](http://www.smartcardfocus.com/shop/ilp/id~524/SmartCafe_Expert_SDK/p/index.shtml)?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse to Java Card development, the cap file is already created in `~your-project-path/bin/your/package/name/javacard/your-project-name.cap` when the project built successfully.

Comment: Only with the right plugins. You should amend your answer to reflect this and point to the plugins...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Java Card converter](http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/kit-user-2.2.2/cJDKconverter.html) to do that.